# Error resolving org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service in Virgo

Tags: cxf, eclipse-virgo, pax, dosgi

I'm trying to get CXF DOSGi to run in Virgo.  I'm using the bundle list with the cxf distribution to create a plan in Virgo.  Virgo is unable to resolve the dependencies on org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service.  Any suggestions on how to get these bundles?

```
Unable to satisfy dependencies of bundle 'org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service' at version '1.7.0': Cannot resolve: org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service
Resolver report:
    Uses violation: <Import-Package: org.ops4j.pax.logging.slf4j; version="[1.7.0,2.0.0)"> in bundle <org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service_1.7.0[1407685751767]>
         Resolver reported uses conflict for import
    Uses violation: <Import-Package: org.eclipse.jetty.security; version="[7.1.0,8.0.0)"> in bundle <org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty_1.1.14[1407685751817]>
         Resolver reported uses conflict for import
    Uses violation: <Import-Package: org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication; version="[7.1.0,8.0.0)"> in bundle <org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty_1.1.14[1407685751817]>
         Resolver reported uses conflict for import
    Uses violation: <Import-Package: org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource; version="[7.1.0,8.0.0)"> in bundle <org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty_1.1.14[1407685751817]>
         Resolver reported uses conflict for import
    Uses violation: <Import-Package: org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl; version="[7.1.0,8.0.0)"> in bundle <org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty_1.1.14[1407685751817]>
         Resolver reported uses conflict for import
    Uses violation: <Import-Package: org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio; version="[7.1.0,8.0.0)"> in bundle <org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty_1.1.14[1407685751817]>
         Resolver reported uses conflict for import
    Uses violation: <Import-Package: org.eclipse.jetty.xml; version="[7.1.0,8.0.0)"> in bundle <org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty_1.1.14[1407685751817]>
         Resolver reported uses conflict for import
    Uses violation: <Import-Package: org.eclipse.jetty.util; version="[7.1.0,8.0.0)"> in bundle <org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty_1.1.14[1407685751817]>
         Resolver reported uses conflict for import
    Uses violation: <Import-Package: org.eclipse.jetty.server; version="[7.1.0,8.0.0)"> in bundle <org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty_1.1.14[1407685751817]>
         Resolver reported uses conflict for import
    Uses violation: <Import-Package: org.eclipse.jetty.util.security; version="[7.1.0,8.0.0)"> in bundle <org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty_1.1.14[1407685751817]>
         Resolver reported uses conflict for import
    Uses violation: <Import-Package: org.eclipse.jetty.servlet; version="[7.1.0,8.0.0)"> in bundle <org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty_1.1.14[1407685751817]>
         Resolver reported uses conflict for import
    Uses violation: <Import-Package: org.eclipse.jetty.io; version="[7.1.0,8.0.0)"> in bundle <org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty_1.1.14[1407685751817]>
         Resolver reported uses conflict for import
    Uses violation: <Import-Package: org.eclipse.jetty.http; version="[7.1.0,8.0.0)"> in bundle <org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty_1.1.14[1407685751817]>
         Resolver reported uses conflict for import
    Uses violation: <Import-Package: org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio; version="[7.1.0,8.0.0)"> in bundle <org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty_1.1.14[1407685751817]>
         Resolver reported uses conflict for import
    Uses violation: <Import-Package: org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler; version="[7.1.0,8.0.0)"> in bundle <org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty_1.1.14[1407685751817]>
         Resolver reported uses conflict for import
    Uses violation: <Import-Package: org.eclipse.jetty.server.session; version="[7.1.0,8.0.0)"> in bundle <org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty_1.1.14[1407685751817]>
         Resolver reported uses conflict for import
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pax-logging-api version 1.70 has incorrect export for the org.apache.juli.logging package. It exports as version 1.0. This is corrected in Pax-logging-api version 1.73.